# Spring Security 4 returns pages as plain/text

Tags: spring-security

I'm migrating from Spring Security 3 to 4 and have an issue with header type of returning page - by default it comes as text/plain and as a result I see just html text instead of real page. In Spring Security 3 everything was working fine

```
<http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/xml/**" security="none"/>

<http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>

    <form-login login-page="/pages/home/login.html"
                default-target-url="/pages/home/entry.html" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                always-use-default-target="true"
                authentication-details-source-ref="authenticationDetailsSource"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/home/login.html" invalidate-session="true"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') or hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS_CLIENT')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/pages/home/login.html"/>

    <anonymous enabled="false"/>

    <custom-filter ref="anonymousAuthenticationFilter" position="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter before="CAS_FILTER" ref="oauthFilter"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <beans:property name="errorPage" value="/pages/home/login.html"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/pages/home/login.html"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Hi, actually no, when I figured out that it is possible to run the code with Spring Security 3 using Spring 4 - it was enough for me that time.